# How to Display a different text on a TextField when selecting an Item From a ComboBox in Javafx?

Tags: java, javafx, combobox

So i want to get a selected item from a Combobox, after clicking on that selected item it should return a different text on a TextField in javafx. I am having a problem in doing so this is my code

I have a ComboBox of type Details , in which I have added few object of Details Class

```
public class Details {

    private final StringProperty ministryOfWater ;
    private final StringProperty ministyOfLands;

    public Details(String ministryOfWater, String ministyOfLands) {
        this.ministryOfWater = new SimpleStringProperty(ministryOfWater);
        this.ministyOfLands = new SimpleStringProperty(ministyOfLands);
    }

    public String getMinistryOfWater() {
        return ministryOfWater.get();
    }

    public void setMinistryOfWater(String ministryOfWater) {
        this.ministryOfWater.set(ministryOfWater);
    }

    public StringProperty ministryOfWaterProperty() {
        return ministryOfWater;
    }
    //finished  ministry of water

    public String getMinistyOfLands() {
        return ministyOfLands.get();
    }

    public void setMinistyOfLands(String ministyOfLands) {
        this.ministyOfLands.set(ministyOfLands);
    }

    public StringProperty ministyOfLandsProperty() {
        return ministyOfLands;
    }

    //finished with the ministry of lands 

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return getMinistryOfWater() + " " + getMinistyOfLands();
    }

}
```

this is my full code

```
package application;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.RichTextString;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.control.DatePicker;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class SafeguardTrackingToolController  implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private TextField txtActivity;
    @FXML
    private TextArea txtComments;
    /*@FXML
    private ComboBox<String> cmbComponent;*/

    @FXML
    private ComboBox<Details> cmbComponent;
    private ObservableList<Details> cmbComponentData = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    @FXML
    private TableColumn 
     tblComponent,
    tblActivity,
    tableColumnForTor,
     tblContract,
    tblfirst,
     tblFinal ,
    tblBank,
     tblDisclosure,
    tblNema,
    tblBudgetRe,
     tblBudgetPro,
     tblBegin,
     tblComments;

    @FXML
    private TableView<Items> tableViewForExcel;

        @FXML
        private DatePicker
     dateTor,
    dateContract,
    dateFirstDraft,
     dateFinalDraft,
     dateBank,
   dateDisclosure,
     dateNema,
   dateBudget,
    dateProvided,
    dateImplementation;

    @FXML
    private Button btnAdd,btnReset
    ,btnCreateAnotherSheet
   ,btnExcel
     ,btnDelete;


    private final ObservableList<Items> data=FXCollections.observableArrayList(new Items(null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null));


    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        tblComponent.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("Component"));
        tblActivity.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("Activity"));
        tableColumnForTor.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("Torr"));
        tblContract.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("Contract"));
        tblfirst.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("FirstDraft"));
        tblFinal.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("FinalDraft"));
        tblBank.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("Bank"));
        tblDisclosure.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("Disclosure"));
        tblNema.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("Nema"));
        tblBudgetRe.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("Budget"));
        tblBudgetPro.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("Provided"));
        tblBegin.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("Implementation"));
        tblComments.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("Comment"));


        cmbComponentData.add(new Details("Ministry of Water",""));
        cmbComponentData.add(new Details("Ministry of Lands",""));
        cmbComponentData.add(new Details("Ministry of Minerals", ""));
        cmbComponentData.add(new Details("Ministry of ManKind", ""));

        if(cmbComponent.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().equals("Ministry of Water")){
            txtActivity.setText("1.0.0");

        } 

        cmbComponent.setItems(cmbComponentData);





        tableViewForExcel.getItems().setAll(this.data);
        tableViewForExcel.setEditable(true);
    }


public static class Items{
        //the setters and getters should be of the same name with the simple string property

        private final SimpleStringProperty Component;
        private final SimpleStringProperty Activity;
        private final SimpleStringProperty Torr;
        private final SimpleStringProperty Contract;
        private final SimpleStringProperty FirstDraft;
        private final SimpleStringProperty FinalDraft;
        private final SimpleStringProperty Bank;
        private final SimpleStringProperty Disclosure;
        private final SimpleStringProperty Nema;
        private final SimpleStringProperty Budget;
        private final SimpleStringProperty Provided;
        private final SimpleStringProperty Implementation;
        private final SimpleStringProperty Comment;

        private Items(String Comp, String Act,
                String Tor, String Co,
                String FDraft, String FinalDra, 
                String Ban, String Dis, String Nem, 
                String Bud,String Pro, String Im,String Comm) {



            this.Component = new SimpleStringProperty(Comp);
            this.Activity = new SimpleStringProperty(Act);
            this.Torr= new SimpleStringProperty(Tor);
            this.Contract= new SimpleStringProperty(Co);
            this.FirstDraft = new SimpleStringProperty(FDraft);
            this.FinalDraft = new SimpleStringProperty(FinalDra);
            this.Bank = new SimpleStringProperty(Ban);
            this.Disclosure = new SimpleStringProperty(Dis);
            this.Nema= new SimpleStringProperty(Nem);
            this.Budget = new SimpleStringProperty(Bud);
            this.Provided = new SimpleStringProperty(Pro);
            this.Implementation= new SimpleStringProperty(Im);
            this.Comment = new SimpleStringProperty(Comm);

        }

        public String getComponent() {
            return Component.get();
        }

        public void setComponent(String Comp) {
            Component.set(Comp);
        }


        public String getActivity() {
            return Activity.get();
        }

        public void setAcivity(String Act) {
            Activity.set(Act);
        }


        public String getTorr() {
            return Torr.get();
        }

        public void setTorr(String Tor) {
            Torr.set(Tor);
        }


        public String getContract() {
            return Contract.get();
        }

        public void setContract(String Co) {
            Contract.set(Co);
        }


        public String getFirstDraft() {
            return FirstDraft.get();
        }

        public void setFirstDraft(String FDraft) {
            FirstDraft.set(FDraft);
        }


        public String getFinalDraft() {
            return FinalDraft.get();
        }

        public void setFinalDraft(String FinalDra) {
            FinalDraft.set(FinalDra);
        }


        public String getBank() {
            return Bank.get();
        }

        public void setBank(String Ban) {
            Bank.set(Ban);
        }


        public String getDisclosure() {
            return Disclosure.get();
        }

        public void setDisclosure(String Dis) {
            Disclosure.set(Dis);
        }


        public String getNema() {
            return Nema.get();
        }

        public void setNema(String Nem) {
            Nema.set(Nem);
        }

        public String getBudget() {
            return Budget.get();
        }

        public void setBudget(String Bud) {
            Budget.set(Bud);
        }


        public String getProvided() {
            return Provided.get();
        }

        public void setProvide(String Pro) {
            Provided.set(Pro);
        }



        public String getImplementation() {
            return Implementation.get();
        }

        public void setImplementation(String Im) {
            Implementation.set(Im);
        }


        public String getComment() {
            return Comment.get();
        }

        public void setComment(String Comm) {
            Comment.set(Comm);
        } 

    }


private void write() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{


    try {


        File myFile=new File("example.xlsx");
        final XSSFWorkbook workbook;
        if (myFile.exists() == false) {
              System.out.println("Creating a new workbook '" + myFile + "'");
         workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();

        }else{
            System.out.println("Appending to existing workbook '" + myFile + "'");
              final InputStream is = new FileInputStream(myFile);
              try {
                  workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(is);
              } finally {
                is.close();
              }

        }
        int sheetIndex = 1;
        while (workbook.getSheet("sample" + sheetIndex) != null) {
          sheetIndex++;
        }

        XSSFSheet spreadsheet = workbook.createSheet("sample");

        XSSFRow row  =null;
        XSSFCell cell=null;

        row= spreadsheet.createRow(0);
        cell = row.createCell(0);
        cell.setCellValue("Component");

        cell = row.createCell(1);
        cell.setCellValue("Activity");

        cell = row.createCell(2);
        cell.setCellValue("TOR");

        cell = row.createCell(3);
        cell.setCellValue("Contract");

        cell = row.createCell(4);
        cell.setCellValue("First Draft");

        cell = row.createCell(5);
        cell.setCellValue("Final Draft");

        cell = row.createCell(6);
        cell.setCellValue("Bank Clearance");

        cell = row.createCell(7);
        cell.setCellValue("Disclosure");

        cell = row.createCell(8);
        cell.setCellValue("NEMA Licence");

        cell = row.createCell(9);
        cell.setCellValue("Budget Request & Prepared");

        cell = row.createCell(10);
        cell.setCellValue("Budget Provided");

        cell = row.createCell(11);
        cell.setCellValue("Begin & Implementation");

        cell = row.createCell(12);
        cell.setCellValue("Comments");



        int i=1;
        for(Items item: tableViewForExcel.getItems()){
                row= spreadsheet.createRow(i);
               // row.createCell(0).setCellValue(item.getComponent());

                cell = row.createCell(0);
                cell.setCellValue(tblComponent.getCellData(1).toString());

                cell = row.createCell(1);
                cell.setCellValue(tblActivity.getCellData(1).toString());

                cell = row.createCell(2);
                cell.setCellValue(tableColumnForTor.getCellData(1).toString());

                cell = row.createCell(3);
                cell.setCellValue(tblContract.getCellData(1).toString());

                cell = row.createCell(4);
                cell.setCellValue(tblfirst.getCellData(1).toString());

                cell = row.createCell(5);
                cell.setCellValue(tblFinal.getCellData(1).toString());

                cell = row.createCell(6);
                cell.setCellValue(tblBank.getCellData(1).toString());

                cell = row.createCell(7);
                cell.setCellValue(tblDisclosure.getCellData(1).toString());

                cell = row.createCell(8);
                cell.setCellValue(tblNema.getCellData(1).toString());

                cell = row.createCell(9);
                cell.setCellValue(tblBudgetRe .getCellData(1).toString());

                cell = row.createCell(10);
                cell.setCellValue(tblBudgetPro.getCellData(1).toString());

                cell = row.createCell(11);
                cell.setCellValue(tblBegin.getCellData(1).toString());

                cell = row.createCell(12);
                cell.setCellValue(tblComments.getCellData(1).toString());

                //.... add other column data as well
                i++;
        }

        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(myFile);
        workbook.write(out);
        out.close();
        System.out.println("Data is wrtten Successfully");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

} 


@FXML
private void onClickToAddOntheTable (ActionEvent event){
            tableViewForExcel.getItems().add(new Items(  
            cmbComponent.getValue().toString(), 
            txtActivity.getText(),
            dateTor.getValue().toString(),
            dateContract.getValue().toString(),
            dateFirstDraft.getValue().toString(),
            dateFinalDraft.getValue().toString(),
            dateBank.getValue().toString(),
            dateDisclosure.getValue().toString(),
            dateNema.getValue().toString(),
            dateBudget.getValue().toString(),
            dateProvided.getValue().toString(),
            dateImplementation.getValue().toString(),

           txtComments.getText()));

            onClickToReset(event);



}

@FXML
private void onClickToSaveInExcel (ActionEvent event){
    try {
        write();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@FXML
private void onClickToReset (ActionEvent event){
    cmbComponent.setValue(null);
    txtActivity.clear();
    dateTor.setValue(null);;
    dateContract.setValue(null);
    dateFirstDraft.setValue(null);
    dateFinalDraft.setValue(null);
    dateBank.setValue(null);
    dateDisclosure.setValue(null);
    dateNema.setValue(null);
    dateBudget.setValue(null);
    dateProvided.setValue(null);
    dateImplementation.setValue(null);
    txtComments.clear();
}



@FXML
private void onClickToResetTable (ActionEvent event){
    tableViewForExcel.getItems().clear();
}


@FXML
private void onClickToCreateAnotherSheet (ActionEvent event){
    LoadAnotherSheet();

}

private void LoadAnotherSheet() {
    Parent root = null;
    try {
        root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("SafeguardTrackingToolNewSheetUI.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        Stage nStage = new Stage();
        nStage.setScene(scene);
        //nStage.setMaximized(true);
        nStage.setTitle("Another Sheet");
        nStage.show();
        Stage stage = (Stage) btnCreateAnotherSheet.getScene().getWindow();
        stage.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}



public class Details {

    private final StringProperty ministryOfWater ;
    private final StringProperty ministyOfLands;

    public Details(String ministryOfWater, String ministyOfLands) {
        this.ministryOfWater = new SimpleStringProperty(ministryOfWater);
        this.ministyOfLands = new SimpleStringProperty(ministyOfLands);
    }

    public String getMinistryOfWater() {
        return ministryOfWater.get();
    }

    public void setMinistryOfWater(String ministryOfWater) {
        this.ministryOfWater.set(ministryOfWater);
    }

    public StringProperty ministryOfWaterProperty() {
        return ministryOfWater;
    }
    //finished  ministry of water

    public String getMinistyOfLands() {
        return ministyOfLands.get();
    }

    public void setMinistyOfLands(String ministyOfLands) {
        this.ministyOfLands.set(ministyOfLands);
    }

    public StringProperty ministyOfLandsProperty() {
        return ministyOfLands;
    }

    //finished with the ministry of lands 

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return getMinistryOfWater() + " " + getMinistyOfLands();
    }

}

}
```

how can i display a different text from selected Combobox to this textfield declared as

TextField txtActivity

i am stuck here

```
if(cmbComponent.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().equals("Ministry of Water")){
            txtActivity.setText("1.0.0");

        }
```

need help
Thanks!

EDIT

I already got the solution from this link 
[How to set text to a TextField when selecting an Item from a Combobox Javafx?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38344118/how-to-set-text-to-a-textfield-when-selecting-an-item-from-a-combobox-javafx/38347332?noredirect=1#comment64121350_38347332)

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your needs you could:

#### Add a listener to the `value` property:

```
cmbComponent.valueProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
    txtActivity.setText(newValue == null ? null : newValue.toString());
});
```

This way the `TextField` will remain editable after selecting the item.

#### Creating a Binding

```
txtActivity.textProperty().bind(Bindings.createStringBinding(() -> {
    Details d = cmbComponent.getValue();
    return d == null ? null : d.toString();
}, cmbComponent.valueProperty()));
```

This way the `TextField` is no longer editable.

#### Add a `TextFormatter` to the `TextField`

This allows bidirectional binding. This way you could change the `ComboBox` value based on the text input in the `TextField`.

```
TextFormatter<Details> formatter = new TextFormatter<>(new StringConverter<Details>() {

    @Override
    public String toString(Details object) {
        return object == null ? "" : object.toString();
    }

    @Override
    public Details fromString(String string) {
        // Return Details object based on String input in TextField
        return string == null || string.isEmpty() ? null : cmbComponent.getItems().stream().filter(d -> string.equals(d.toString())).findAny().orElse(null);
    }

});

txtActivity.setTextFormatter(formatter);

cmbComponent.valueProperty().bindBidirectional(formatter.valueProperty());
```

Comment: nope it dint work ...i edited the question if you could see please help