# How to set text to a TextField when selecting an Item from a Combobox Javafx?

Tags: java, javafx, combobox

I want to get the selected item from the combobox, after the event click it displays a different text on a TextField declared as txtActivity

I am stuck at this point at which the code is not working 
need help

am stuck at this point

```
if(cmbComponent.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().equals("Ministry of Water")){
    txtActivity.setText("1.0.0");

}
```

This is my full code

```
package application;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.RichTextString;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.control.DatePicker;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class SafeguardTrackingToolController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private TextField txtActivity;
    @FXML
    private TextArea txtComments;
    /*@FXML
    private ComboBox<String> cmbComponent;*/

    @FXML
    private ComboBox < Details > cmbComponent;
    private ObservableList < Details > cmbComponentData = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    @FXML
    private TableColumn
    tblComponent,
    tblActivity,
    tableColumnForTor,
    tblContract,
    tblfirst,
    tblFinal,
    tblBank,
    tblDisclosure,
    tblNema,
    tblBudgetRe,
    tblBudgetPro,
    tblBegin,
    tblComments;

    @FXML
    private TableView < Items > tableViewForExcel;

    @FXML
    private DatePicker
    dateTor,
    dateContract,
    dateFirstDraft,
    dateFinalDraft,
    dateBank,
    dateDisclosure,
    dateNema,
    dateBudget,
    dateProvided,
    dateImplementation;

    @FXML
    private Button btnAdd, btnReset, btnCreateAnotherSheet, btnExcel, btnDelete;


    private final ObservableList < Items > data = FXCollections.observableArrayList(new Items(null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null));


    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        tblComponent.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("Component"));
        tblActivity.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("Activity"));
        tableColumnForTor.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("Torr"));
        tblContract.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("Contract"));
        tblfirst.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("FirstDraft"));
        tblFinal.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("FinalDraft"));
        tblBank.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("Bank"));
        tblDisclosure.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("Disclosure"));
        tblNema.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("Nema"));
        tblBudgetRe.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("Budget"));
        tblBudgetPro.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("Provided"));
        tblBegin.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("Implementation"));
        tblComments.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("Comment"));


        cmbComponentData.add(new Details("Ministry of Water", ""));
        cmbComponentData.add(new Details("Ministry of Lands", ""));
        cmbComponentData.add(new Details("Ministry of Minerals", ""));
        cmbComponentData.add(new Details("Ministry of ManKind", ""));

        if (cmbComponent.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().equals("Ministry of Water")) {
            txtActivity.setText("1.0.0");

        }

        cmbComponent.setItems(cmbComponentData);




        tableViewForExcel.getItems().setAll(this.data);
        tableViewForExcel.setEditable(true);
    }


    public static class Items {
        //the setters and getters should be of the same name with the simple string property

        private final SimpleStringProperty Component;
        private final SimpleStringProperty Activity;
        private final SimpleStringProperty Torr;
        private final SimpleStringProperty Contract;
        private final SimpleStringProperty FirstDraft;
        private final SimpleStringProperty FinalDraft;
        private final SimpleStringProperty Bank;
        private final SimpleStringProperty Disclosure;
        private final SimpleStringProperty Nema;
        private final SimpleStringProperty Budget;
        private final SimpleStringProperty Provided;
        private final SimpleStringProperty Implementation;
        private final SimpleStringProperty Comment;

        private Items(String Comp, String Act,
            String Tor, String Co,
            String FDraft, String FinalDra,
            String Ban, String Dis, String Nem,
            String Bud, String Pro, String Im, String Comm) {



            this.Component = new SimpleStringProperty(Comp);
            this.Activity = new SimpleStringProperty(Act);
            this.Torr = new SimpleStringProperty(Tor);
            this.Contract = new SimpleStringProperty(Co);
            this.FirstDraft = new SimpleStringProperty(FDraft);
            this.FinalDraft = new SimpleStringProperty(FinalDra);
            this.Bank = new SimpleStringProperty(Ban);
            this.Disclosure = new SimpleStringProperty(Dis);
            this.Nema = new SimpleStringProperty(Nem);
            this.Budget = new SimpleStringProperty(Bud);
            this.Provided = new SimpleStringProperty(Pro);
            this.Implementation = new SimpleStringProperty(Im);
            this.Comment = new SimpleStringProperty(Comm);

        }

        public String getComponent() {
            return Component.get();
        }

        public void setComponent(String Comp) {
            Component.set(Comp);
        }


        public String getActivity() {
            return Activity.get();
        }

        public void setAcivity(String Act) {
            Activity.set(Act);
        }


        public String getTorr() {
            return Torr.get();
        }

        public void setTorr(String Tor) {
            Torr.set(Tor);
        }


        public String getContract() {
            return Contract.get();
        }

        public void setContract(String Co) {
            Contract.set(Co);
        }


        public String getFirstDraft() {
            return FirstDraft.get();
        }

        public void setFirstDraft(String FDraft) {
            FirstDraft.set(FDraft);
        }


        public String getFinalDraft() {
            return FinalDraft.get();
        }

        public void setFinalDraft(String FinalDra) {
            FinalDraft.set(FinalDra);
        }


        public String getBank() {
            return Bank.get();
        }

        public void setBank(String Ban) {
            Bank.set(Ban);
        }


        public String getDisclosure() {
            return Disclosure.get();
        }

        public void setDisclosure(String Dis) {
            Disclosure.set(Dis);
        }


        public String getNema() {
            return Nema.get();
        }

        public void setNema(String Nem) {
            Nema.set(Nem);
        }

        public String getBudget() {
            return Budget.get();
        }

        public void setBudget(String Bud) {
            Budget.set(Bud);
        }


        public String getProvided() {
            return Provided.get();
        }

        public void setProvide(String Pro) {
            Provided.set(Pro);
        }



        public String getImplementation() {
            return Implementation.get();
        }

        public void setImplementation(String Im) {
            Implementation.set(Im);
        }


        public String getComment() {
            return Comment.get();
        }

        public void setComment(String Comm) {
            Comment.set(Comm);
        }

    }


    private void write() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {


        try {


            File myFile = new File("example.xlsx");
            final XSSFWorkbook workbook;
            if (myFile.exists() == false) {
                System.out.println("Creating a new workbook '" + myFile + "'");
                workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();

            } else {
                System.out.println("Appending to existing workbook '" + myFile + "'");
                final InputStream is = new FileInputStream(myFile);
                try {
                    workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(is);
                } finally {
                    is.close();
                }

            }
            int sheetIndex = 1;
            while (workbook.getSheet("sample" + sheetIndex) != null) {
                sheetIndex++;
            }

            XSSFSheet spreadsheet = workbook.createSheet("sample");

            XSSFRow row = null;
            XSSFCell cell = null;

            row = spreadsheet.createRow(0);
            cell = row.createCell(0);
            cell.setCellValue("Component");

            cell = row.createCell(1);
            cell.setCellValue("Activity");

            cell = row.createCell(2);
            cell.setCellValue("TOR");

            cell = row.createCell(3);
            cell.setCellValue("Contract");

            cell = row.createCell(4);
            cell.setCellValue("First Draft");

            cell = row.createCell(5);
            cell.setCellValue("Final Draft");

            cell = row.createCell(6);
            cell.setCellValue("Bank Clearance");

            cell = row.createCell(7);
            cell.setCellValue("Disclosure");

            cell = row.createCell(8);
            cell.setCellValue("NEMA Licence");

            cell = row.createCell(9);
            cell.setCellValue("Budget Request & Prepared");

            cell = row.createCell(10);
            cell.setCellValue("Budget Provided");

            cell = row.createCell(11);
            cell.setCellValue("Begin & Implementation");

            cell = row.createCell(12);
            cell.setCellValue("Comments");



            int i = 1;
            for (Items item: tableViewForExcel.getItems()) {
                row = spreadsheet.createRow(i);
                // row.createCell(0).setCellValue(item.getComponent());

                cell = row.createCell(0);
                cell.setCellValue(tblComponent.getCellData(1).toString());

                cell = row.createCell(1);
                cell.setCellValue(tblActivity.getCellData(1).toString());

                cell = row.createCell(2);
                cell.setCellValue(tableColumnForTor.getCellData(1).toString());

                cell = row.createCell(3);
                cell.setCellValue(tblContract.getCellData(1).toString());

                cell = row.createCell(4);
                cell.setCellValue(tblfirst.getCellData(1).toString());

                cell = row.createCell(5);
                cell.setCellValue(tblFinal.getCellData(1).toString());

                cell = row.createCell(6);
                cell.setCellValue(tblBank.getCellData(1).toString());

                cell = row.createCell(7);
                cell.setCellValue(tblDisclosure.getCellData(1).toString());

                cell = row.createCell(8);
                cell.setCellValue(tblNema.getCellData(1).toString());

                cell = row.createCell(9);
                cell.setCellValue(tblBudgetRe.getCellData(1).toString());

                cell = row.createCell(10);
                cell.setCellValue(tblBudgetPro.getCellData(1).toString());

                cell = row.createCell(11);
                cell.setCellValue(tblBegin.getCellData(1).toString());

                cell = row.createCell(12);
                cell.setCellValue(tblComments.getCellData(1).toString());

                //.... add other column data as well
                i++;
            }

            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(myFile);
            workbook.write(out);
            out.close();
            System.out.println("Data is wrtten Successfully");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }


    @FXML
    private void onClickToAddOntheTable(ActionEvent event) {
        tableViewForExcel.getItems().add(new Items(
            cmbComponent.getValue().toString(),
            txtActivity.getText(),
            dateTor.getValue().toString(),
            dateContract.getValue().toString(),
            dateFirstDraft.getValue().toString(),
            dateFinalDraft.getValue().toString(),
            dateBank.getValue().toString(),
            dateDisclosure.getValue().toString(),
            dateNema.getValue().toString(),
            dateBudget.getValue().toString(),
            dateProvided.getValue().toString(),
            dateImplementation.getValue().toString(),

            txtComments.getText()));

        onClickToReset(event);



    }

    @FXML
    private void onClickToSaveInExcel(ActionEvent event) {
        try {
            write();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @FXML
    private void onClickToReset(ActionEvent event) {
        cmbComponent.setValue(null);
        txtActivity.clear();
        dateTor.setValue(null);;
        dateContract.setValue(null);
        dateFirstDraft.setValue(null);
        dateFinalDraft.setValue(null);
        dateBank.setValue(null);
        dateDisclosure.setValue(null);
        dateNema.setValue(null);
        dateBudget.setValue(null);
        dateProvided.setValue(null);
        dateImplementation.setValue(null);
        txtComments.clear();
    }



    @FXML
    private void onClickToResetTable(ActionEvent event) {
        tableViewForExcel.getItems().clear();
    }


    @FXML
    private void onClickToCreateAnotherSheet(ActionEvent event) {
        LoadAnotherSheet();

    }

    private void LoadAnotherSheet() {
        Parent root = null;
        try {
            root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("SafeguardTrackingToolNewSheetUI.fxml"));
            Scene scene = new Scene(root);
            Stage nStage = new Stage();
            nStage.setScene(scene);
            //nStage.setMaximized(true);
            nStage.setTitle("Another Sheet");
            nStage.show();
            Stage stage = (Stage) btnCreateAnotherSheet.getScene().getWindow();
            stage.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }



    public class Details {

        private final StringProperty ministryOfWater;
        private final StringProperty ministyOfLands;

        public Details(String ministryOfWater, String ministyOfLands) {
            this.ministryOfWater = new SimpleStringProperty(ministryOfWater);
            this.ministyOfLands = new SimpleStringProperty(ministyOfLands);
        }

        public String getMinistryOfWater() {
            return ministryOfWater.get();
        }

        public void setMinistryOfWater(String ministryOfWater) {
            this.ministryOfWater.set(ministryOfWater);
        }

        public StringProperty ministryOfWaterProperty() {
                return ministryOfWater;
            }
            //finished  ministry of water

        public String getMinistyOfLands() {
            return ministyOfLands.get();
        }

        public void setMinistyOfLands(String ministyOfLands) {
            this.ministyOfLands.set(ministyOfLands);
        }

        public StringProperty ministyOfLandsProperty() {
            return ministyOfLands;
        }

        //finished with the ministry of lands 

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return getMinistryOfWater() + " " + getMinistyOfLands();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Display a different text on a TextField when selecting an Item From a ComboBox in Javafx?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38331356/how-to-display-a-different-text-on-a-textfield-when-selecting-an-item-from-a-com)

Comment: yeah but there was no answer in that link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `getSelectedItem()` is called, the selection is `null`, so your predicate always fails. One approach would be set the desired index and test it.

```
cmbComponent.getSelectionModel().selectFirst();
if (cmbComponent.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex() == 0) {
    txtActivity.setText("1.0.0");
}
```

> I tried using the `else if` condition to set another text like "2.0.0" it won't respond.

Looking at your previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38331356/230513) on this topic, it looks like you want to update the `TextField` when the `ComboBox` changes. Implementing the [first approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38335121/230513) suggested by @fabian, the updated example below adds a `ChangeListener` to the `ComboBox`. The listener fetches the required text from the selected instance of `Details` and uses it to update the `TextField`.

[image]

As tested:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 * @see https://stackoverflow.com/a/38347332/230513
 */
public class ComboBoxTest extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        primaryStage.setTitle("ComboBoxTest");

        final TextField txtActivity = new TextField();
        final ComboBox cmbComponent = new ComboBox();
        ObservableList<Details> cmbComponentData = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        cmbComponentData.add(new Details("Ministry of Water", "1.0.0"));
        cmbComponentData.add(new Details("Ministry of Lands", "2.0.0"));
        cmbComponentData.add(new Details("Ministry of Minerals", "3.0.0"));
        cmbComponentData.add(new Details("Ministry of ManKind", "4.0.0"));
        cmbComponent.setItems(cmbComponentData);
        cmbComponent.getSelectionModel().selectFirst();
        txtActivity.setText(cmbComponentData.get(0).getText());
        cmbComponent.valueProperty().addListener((o, ov, nv) -> {
            Details d = (Details) nv;
            txtActivity.setText(d.getText());
        });

        VBox root = new VBox();
        root.getChildren().addAll(cmbComponent, txtActivity);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private static class Details {

        private final StringProperty name;
        private final StringProperty text;

        public Details(String name, String text) {
            this.name = new SimpleStringProperty(name);
            this.text = new SimpleStringProperty(text);
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name.get();
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name.set(name);
        }

        public StringProperty nameProperty() {
            return name;
        }

        public String getText() {
            return text.get();
        }

        public void setText(String text) {
            this.text.set(text);
        }

        public StringProperty textProperty() {
            return text;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return getName();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Comment: i tried your solution but it only outputs the first text "1.0.0".I tried using the else if condition to set another text like "2.0.0" it wont respond

Comment: I've elaborated above.